# Segmentation fault with array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am writing a fairly simple code to enter integers stored in a file into an array of moderate size, but on compiling and running the code, it gives Segmentation fault error, can anyone please correct me where I am making a mistake, the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[100000];
    ifstream f;
    f.open("IntegerArray.txt");
    string line;

    if (f.is_open())
    {
        int i=0;
        while (f.good())
        {
            getline(f,line);
            arr[i++] = atoi(line.c_str());
        }
        f.close();
    }
    else
        cout<<"file not open";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow on stackoverflow... :D

Comment: How many lines do you have in IntegerArray.txt?

Comment: I think you have more than 100000 lines in your IntegerArray.txt.

Comment: IntegerArray.txt has 100,000 lines

Comment: [Do not read while(good)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). (The question title mentions eof(), but the same reasoning applies)

Comment: using eof() also gives seg fault.. :(

Comment: correct. You need to check for every read whether you had any read error.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead of your raw array. If you know it's going to be exactly 100000, then `std::array` would be a bit better if you can use it.

Comment: after the last read, the stream has not reached eof() and is still good(). So you need to check it right before you use the last read data!

Comment: I didn't say to change it to eof(). Just read the answers to the other question I linked.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, ok sorry, I misunderstood your comment, it works now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

After rading a line from a file with `getline()`, the stream should be checked for potential errors, for example with `.fail()`, which:

> Returns true if either (or both) the failbit or the badbit error state flags is set for the stream.

```
while (f.good())
{
    getline(f,line);

    if (f.fail()) {
        cout << "Corrupt data" << endl; // example output
        break;
    }

    // everything ok, continue with logic
    arr[i++] = atoi(line.c_str());
}
```